# Using a cached copy of autodiscover.xml

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I'm having trouble implementing EWS in my application. The exchange server in question is not allowing a connection, however I think I can solve it by implementing NTLM as an authentication method.

Before I do that, however, I'd like to know if it is possible to use a local copy of autodiscover.xml cached by Outlook, since it appears to contain the necessary information. Can I do this? Furthermore, if I can do this, is it a good or a bad idea?

Comment: You could simply tell the service the URL for the EWS Service, and not use autodiscover at all.

Comment: I've tried this, however I get ServiceVersionException. I know that the account exists, and I know that I'm specifying the correct version, thus I am assuming that there's some supplementary information in the XML that I am missing - a cursory glance at the cached copy per Outlook shows a lot of configuration, so this is my first thought.